# SystemError is raised after attempt to create function with positional-only args in runtime inside other one

Tags: python, function, annotations, python-3.8, positional-argument

There is some test code:

```
some_type = int

def func0():
    def func1(arg: some_type, /):
        pass

func0()
```

And I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
...
SystemError: no locals when loading 'some_type'
```

However the code below works as expected:

```
some_type = int

def func0():
    def func1(arg: some_type):
        pass

func0()
```

And this one is also valid:

```
some_type = int
exec('''
def func1(arg: some_type, /):
    pass
''')
```

I know that annotations will no longer be evaluated at definition time in future versions; also it is possible to activate such behaviour in 3.7+ versions. Something like

```
from __future__ import annotations
some_type = int

def func0():
    def func1(arg: some_type, /):
        pass

func0()
```

has no problems as well. However, the question is about the current strange behaviour at function definition time. `some_type` is in no way a local variable of `func0`, though python thinks so. One more fine version:

```
def func0():
    some_type = int
    def func1(arg: some_type, /):
        pass

func0()
```

I've read [PEP 570](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/) but not found anything about annotations declarations there.

My python version:

```
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

Comment: This looks likely to me like a bug within python... adding a parameter with the type after the positional only operator will also "fix" the problem, `def func1(arg: some_type, /, bar: some_type)` (error persists if no typing is provided)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in cpython -- I've opened an issue for it here: https://bugs.python.org/issue39215

looking at the disassembly of the two functions, it appears as though it incorrectly uses `LOAD_NAME` instead of `LOAD_GLOBAL` when building the annotation type -- here's the diff between one with and without positional only arguments:

```
$ diff -u <(python3.9 -m dis t2.py | sed 's/0x[a-f0-9]*/0xdeadbeef/g;s/t2\.py/FILENAME/g') <(python3.9 -m dis t3.py | sed 's/0x[a-f0-9]*/0xdeadbeef/g;s/t3\.py/FILENAME/g')
--- /dev/fd/63  2020-01-04 16:34:27.372004436 -0800
+++ /dev/fd/62  2020-01-04 16:34:27.372004436 -0800
@@ -10,7 +10,7 @@
              16 RETURN_VALUE

 Disassembly of <code object f at 0xdeadbeef, file "FILENAME", line 1>:
-  2           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (int)
+  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (int)
               2 LOAD_CONST               1 (('arg',))
               4 BUILD_CONST_KEY_MAP      1
               6 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object g at 0xdeadbeef, file "FILENAME", line 2>)
```

---

**EDIT**: and here's a pull request to fix this (should land in 3.8.2 and 3.9.0a3 if my guess about timing is correct): https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/17826

Comment: You are right. It seems that there are also similar problems with `LOAD_DEREF`